# Shared Columns in XPages?

Tags: xpages

One of the better recent enhancements to Notes was the shared columns for views.   I could set width. fonts, all kinds of settings and place a shared column in a view.  If I needed to say, change a column width, I changed it in one place and it changed across all of my views.

Is there anyway to do this in an xPage view?   There does not seem to be a view column so there does not seem to be a way to create a custom control.

Any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom control for every shared column like I did in customer app.

```
<xp:viewColumn columnName="lastmodified" id="viewColumn4">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertDateTime>
                <xp:this.pattern><![CDATA[${javascript:app.getResourceString("language","DATE_FORMAT")}]]></xp:this.pattern>
            </xp:convertDateTime>
        </xp:this.converter>
        <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader4">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:app.getResourceString("language","COLUMNHEADER_LASTMODIFIED")}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
```

Comment: I tried that but how do you insert it into the actual control?  Do you need to insert it into the source?  Or is there a way to use the Design tab, if so how?

Comment: When you add a viewpanel to your XPage and select columns to add, you will get your column syntax in the source view.
There you can add directly after the end viewcolumn tag your custom control.
Important is that the columnname should be present in the view which you use.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you must get into the source and cannot do this with designer?

Comment: No that is not exactly what I mean. Everything can be done in the designer. If you open a XPage there is a Design tab and a Source tab. To add the custom viewcolumn it is better to do this in the Source Tab. You will have more control on adding code to the XPage. I can send you an example database.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant to use the Source tab and that is the way I did it.  Can it be done with the Design tab?  If so how?

Comment: It can be done in the design tab, but it is much harder. Less control of where the custom control will 'land'. I wrote a blog about this question: http://www.domino-weblog.nl/weblogs/Domino_Blog.nsf/dx/shared-columns-in-xpages-an-example.htm